# Visual studio 2022 Remote Debugging Debian/Linux Authentication Error

Tags: linux, visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging, orange-pi

I'm getting an error trying to remote debug(Visual Studio 2022) on an SBC(orangepi) that is running Debian 11. I have an ASPNET dotnet core application running that I want to debug. I am entering the same information that I'm using to success connect SSH with Bitvise and winscp. Visual studio is telling me that there is an authentication issue which there isn't.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you double-checked the password is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is not the issue.

Comment: That always worked fine for me, not sure what could be the difference here.

Comment: I tried it again with a new user I created but no success. I am running debian on an orangepi. I had this issue before when I tried it on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by running bitvise and connection over SSH. I also entered the username as root for the login. It might be a permissions issue with orangepi that wouldn't allow it to connect?

Also note, I had to build as ARM64 as that's what the board has. If I ran the program as SUDO, i had to remote debug as root@ip.